# What are these wooden glass dividers called (cabiner window dividers)?

Tags: repair, wood, cabinets, glass

I'm replacing broken glass in my display cabinet door, with glass on order.

When removing the old glass and glazing I tried to salvage as much as I could, including the thin wooden strips that divided the glass pieces. However, it is clear that they are unsalvageable and need replacing also. The only issue is... I have no idea what they are called or where to buy them.

Can anybody help?

I am assuming they are a specialist piece, rather than just a wooden strip?

I have measured the dimensions to be: 18mm (height) x 1mm (width) x however long they need to be.

I did find something like **[this](https://www.cornwallmodelboats.co.uk/acatalog/Amati-Walnut-Strip-1x1mm-A2410_01.html)** online for model boat making; I'm nust not sure if it's suitable and could do with some guidance.

**FYI:** I should also state that the strips should be flexible enough to fit the shape seen in the pictures below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like veneer.  You might visit a local woodworkers shop (in the USA Rockler is an example) and check out their veneer supplies.  I suspect you'll find something that will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That part of the window is known as the "muntin", so these would be "curved muntins" - although I couldn't find much about them.  From the pictures you posted, it appears to be some kind of thin plywood, with the outer layers oriented perpendicular to the window surface to better bend.  Veneer is definitely also an option, and probably the simplest way to get wood that thin.  Most of the structure holding the glass just comes from the glazing.

If you do use veneer, try to orient the pieces so that the grain helps you bend them, don't try to bend against the grain.  Some steam, or ironing them between damp cloths might help.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. For the time being, I have taken the chance on spending £6 on a few lengths of 1mm lime from the model boat website I liked to above, but if this doesn't work, I will see about getting some veneer :-)